# structuring custom angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add a few custom angular directives to be called on several views. that said, below is how I have the code setup

app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'app.routes',
        'app.config',
        'app.users',
        'app.plans'
    ]);
```

usersCtrl.js

```
angular
    .module('app.users.controllers')
    .controller('usersCtrl', usersCtrl)

usersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$window'];

function usersCtrl($scope, $http, $window) {
    /*controller code here*/
}
```

plansCtrl.js

```
angular
    .module('app.plans.controllers')
    .controller('plansCtrl', plansCtrl)

plansCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$window'];

function plansCtrl($scope, $http, $window) {
    /*controller code here*/
}
```

now if I add directive to say users like below

usersCtrl.js with a directive attached

```
angular
    .module('app.users.controllers')
    .controller('usersCtrl', usersCtrl)
    .directive('myFirstDirective', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {

                alert('my first directive')

            }
        };
    }]);

usersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$window'];

function usersCtrl($scope, $http, $window) {
    /*controller code here*/
}
```

with the above setting if I call directive on users view it works as it should but then if I call it within plan view it also works. that being said, what's the best way to structure directives), where to place custom directive and access those where needed.

Comment: What do you mean _"best way to structure directives"_ and _"where to place custom directive and access those where needed."_? Please make your question more specific

Comment: wanna create a few helper directives, say for image upload and call them where needed

Answer (score 1):

Since your directive is module independent and can be shared between different module, my suggestion would be to create a commonmodule and declare your directive in that module. Then you can either register that to global app like other module and use it.

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'app.routes',
        'app.config', 
        'app.commonmodule',
        'app.plans'
        'app.users',
        'app.plans'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using directives correctly.

[From AngularJS documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's
>   HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM
>   element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM
>   element and its children.

In the above code, your directive has nothing to do with the DOM elements. It just sends an alert. Therefore you should create a [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) instead of directive to do so.